# biblatex: Max names in alphabetic citation key

Tags: biblatex, author-number

Is it possible to set the number of names to appear in a bibliography entry differently from the maximum number of names that appear in the citation key (using `alphabetic` style)?

For example,

```
[ABCD06] Alice, Bob, Carol, and David. "Title", 2006.
[ABC+06] Alice, Bob, Carol, David, and Eve. "Title Revisted," 2007
```

This is how `alpha` behaves in BibTeX. With four authors, all are listed in both the entry and the citekey. With five or more, all authors are still listed in the entry but only the first three (with a +) are listed in the citekey.

I played a little (without luck) with `maxnames`, `maxcitenames`, and `mincitenames` but figured it will be quicker to just ask.

Comment: `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames` isn't it? At least in the latest biblatex...

Comment: or add a different `maxnames` option to the `\printbibliography` command itself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{test1,
  author = {Alice and Bob and Carol and David},
  year = {2006},
  title = {Title},
}
@misc{test2,
  author = {Alice and Bob and Carol and David and Eve},
  year = {2007},
  title = {Title revisited},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{test1,test2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: My answer relies on a [message](http://groups.google.com/group/de.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/a119c7e159085ea6/3039c0f625a0669a?) from Philipp Lehman, the author of `biblatex`, at de.comp.text.tex on December 29th, 2010. The significant quote (translated by me):

> Relevant for the "alpha" labels is the value of `maxnames`/`minnames`
>   set at `\begin{document}`. The labels are fixed from this point
>   forward. You may freely choose how many names to display afterwards.

EDIT2: When using the package option `maxbibnames=99`, `maxnames`/`minnames` must be set in addition; setting `maxcitenames`/`mincitenames` won't produce the desired "alpha" label format.

Comment: A later answer to a similar question suggests using `maxalphanames`/`minalphanames`, upon which this works as expected for me. → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29648/16666