# Short harvard citation?

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

I need to cite the following way:

The first 3 Letters of the author + the year.

Example:

> Kemper 2009 --> [Kem09]

But I don't have any clue how to do that!

Answer (score 11):

This is the standard with biblatex’s style `alphabetic`, as long as you have one author. With multiple authors, this style takes the first letter of every author – up to three, as a default. If there are more than three authors, it takes the first three letters of the first name, then a `+` and the year, e.g.

> Kemper 2009 > [Kem09]
>
> Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin 1994 > [GSM94]
>
> Kemper et al. 2011 > [Kem+11]

**Edit:**

As Audrey stated in the comments, you can change the name of the authors that are used for the alphabetic label with the option `maxalphanames`. With `maxalphanames=1`, the above examples would look like this:

> Kemper 2009 > [Kem09]
>
> Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin 1994 > [Goo+94]
>
> Kemper et al. 2011 > [Kem+11]

If you want to get rid of the `+`, you can redefine the `\labelalphaothers` command: `\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}`

Comment: i know, but every entry should have this format, not the aplha format

Comment: @el.paso You can use the options `style=alphabetic,maxalphanames=1`. If the first three letters of the first author's last name and last two digits of the year don't specify a unique entry, a suffix is added. For example: `Kem09a`, `Kem09b`.

Comment: @Audrey, thanks for this, I didn’t know that (since I am not using the alphabetic styles). I edited my answer correspondingly.

Comment: @domwass No problem. I think that option is relatively new. I actually didn't know about `\labelalphaothers` myself, but now I do.

Comment: @Audrey, actually, I didn’t know about `\labelalphaothers` myself, until I looked it up for this answer (c; So I learned two things …